# Can sub states in composite state share the same state(name?) in UML state diagram

Tags: uml, state, diagram, composite

I have a composite state : Post-Exam

in the composite state i have 2 sub state both call Post-Exam but both of them do separate events , is this allowed in the UML state diagram?  its something like this :

```
( Post-Exam )---->(                                                     )
                  ( Start -> (Post-Exam / Do : show marks ) ---> end    )
                  ( Start -> (Post-Exam / Do : reward student) ---> end )
                  (                                                     ) --> something else.
```

Is this allowed in the UML state diagram? with sub states having the same name , because i wanna do 2 events while being in Post-Exam state.

Comment: and you want to do them in parallel? otherwise you could just `do: show marks; reward student` and not create several extra states.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that like this:

[image]

As mentioned in the comment the substates are executed concurrently. This is shown by the fork after the entry point. The 2nd fork assures that only after both substates are finished the whole state will finalize.